# Internationalization using SPRING MVC

Tags: java, spring, internationalization

Below is the project-structure showing where I keep my messages files:

- Web
- Java Resources
- src/main/resources
- messages_en.properties
- messages_fr.properties

Bean configuration file where I define message source looks like as shown below:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
<property name="basenames">
<list>
<value>messages_fr</value>
</list>
</property>
</bean>
```

I am new to this concept of internationalization. So don't know much except that if you put your .properies file inside the tag it will be picked and changes will be reflected. But I am facing problem in dealing with multiple .properties files. 
Say If I have more than one .properties file then how should I implement locale changes? How would the program know which file to take?

Answer (score 0):

You should use :

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
    <list>
        <value>messages</value>
    </list>
    </property>
</bean>enter code here
```

Spring will use the local specified when you are calling the message bundle, so you don't have to specify it the declaration of your bundle.

Note : I think that you have to name your file :
messages_fr_FR.properties or messages_en_EN.properties.

Edit :

You can specify a local using :

```
messageSource.getMessage("messageKey", args, Locale.FRANCE);
```

to use messages_fr_FR

or

```
messageSource.getMessage("messageKey", args,LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
```

to use the local selected by the user.

I hope it may help you

Comment: My doubt is how would the application know which file to take. Do I need to pass some kind of parameter or need to change browser language  to see the change.

Comment: It depend to how will you call the message bundle I will add example to my post.

Comment: I it important to write a controller to see the changes.

Comment: Yes, but you can also call it from view.